# When deserializing JSON are the arguments just being set?

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I'm trying to understand the processing order of when the system is deserializing the JSON data.

Are the arguments just being set on the creation of POJOs?
or are the arguments being set by calls to the various setSomeArg(String someValu) methods?

I'm not finding my answer via searches or Google.
Appreciate any insight into this. If this is a duplicate to a posting already in SO please post a link and not just say it is a duplicate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The deserialization process uses introspection/reflection, which means it will check for attributes having the same same as what was found in the JSON and then set the value according to your class attribute type (i.e. it will cast the value to integer if it is an integer).

The process is recursive, so if your POJO has an other POJO as attribute, it will try to parse the value of the JSON as an object, untill every attribute is set.
I don't know which library you are using, but Genson, for example, demands a constructor without attributes, in order to call it through introspection/reflection in a way that looks like

```
POJO myPojo = POJO.class.newInstance();
```

Then, it will set each attribute in a way like :

```
long value = Long.ParseLong(myJson.get('value'));
// The example field is a long int
Field f = POJO.getClass().getDeclaredField("aFieldName");
f.setLong(myPojo, value);
```

If you want a more complete example, have a look at the javadoc :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html

Comment: I'm using the FasterXML.Jackson library. I do understand the above, it is just the actual setting of the value I'm curious about. It the attribute set by just setting the attribute to the value in the JSON or does it utilize the setSomeMethod() that is defined in the POJO for that attribute?

Comment: I just edited to answer to match your comment. The "setLong(objectConcerned, value)" is, I think, the method you are looking for.

Comment: Just so we're on the same page, you are saying that when JSON is deserialized into the pojo, the pojo attributes are being set by the method setSomeArg(String someValu) and this is always the case, Right?